# So even though the raw materials of semiconductors are cheap why is their cost so high and why don't we use conductor for the same job?

Tags: electrical-engineering, semiconductor

The materials used in making semiconductor are cheap and readily available then does the cost of processors so high can't we use metals like copper and iron which very good conductor for manufacturing these processors.

Comment: 1) Because of the behavior of the materials, 2) the costs of processing said materials.

Comment: By "processors" I assume you mean integrated circuit chips. If so, you appear to have a misunderstanding of why they need to be made from semiconducting materials & not conducting materials. Look at the origins of the transistor & then look at how integrated circuit chip are manufactured & why the process is complex - which adds to the cost.

Comment: How do you propose to switch a piece of copper or iron off and on?

Comment: I used to work with pre-silicon computers. The adder drawer weighed 125 pounds and the rack system came with its own generator

Comment: I also worked on an old lasagna-making machine controlled by relay logic. The control panel was 48 feet long and had 8000 relays - most of them custom jobs.

Comment: I would like to disagree with the cost issue. Its just the best of the best processors that are expensive. Best of the best usually is expensive. And even they aren't all that expensive all things considered. I mean if your processing needs are low then you can get processors that cost cents.

Answer (score 1):

The raw material for a semiconductor may only be sand.  But sand is an insulator.  It has to be processed into ultra-pure silicon.  The sizes of features in a modern semiconductor are measured in nanometres.  So even one speck of dust getting into that silicon can ruin one microchip.  So everything has to be done in an ultra-clean environment.  Which means expensive machines.

Ordinary conductors aren't much use.  The clever bit about semiconductors is that they can be switched on and off by applying small voltages or currents to their inputs.  A conductor is always on.

Answer (score 0):

To produce every new successive generation of nodes and transistors, the machinery must be constantly upgraded to accommodate it.
Moores LAW. Which states the amount of transistors on a microchip Double every generation (18-24 months)
[image]
The manufacturing process for each successive chip becomes more quality control difficulty and energy intensive. But per capita, is actually cheaper.

The 1st Microprocessor to commercially go on sale was Intel 4004.
It had 2,300 transistors and cost 60 dollars in 1971. (450 dollars USD today 2023 money)[image]

Apple' M3 chip has 37 BILLION transistors. [image] THou not sold individually, is probably in 400-600 dollar range but is 16 million times more transistors[image]